# RSS news feeds for my commercial website

Tags: php, html, rss, rss-reader

I would like to implement RSS Feeds API on my commercial website. Most of the feeds sources seem to be applicable only for non-commercial use. Where can I get RSS Feeds? 
I found many feeders like feedzilla, reuter and others; but I am not sure if they can be used for my site. Reuter has specifically mentioned only for individual or non-profit organization.
Has anyone tried feedzilla or other feeders?

Thank You.

Comment: I use feedity for these type of things. It's great and give many functionalities!

http://feedity.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use feedity for these type of things. It's great and give many functionalities!

http://feedity.com/

Answer (score 0):

I use feedroll for feeds.It is kind of simple.
 http://www.feedroll.com/rssviewer/